# trouble with variables value not available

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, oxygenxml

Assuming that :

```
   <xsl:variable name="eur-uri" select="resolve-uri('prices/eur.xml',base-uri())"/>
   <xsl:variable name="eur-node" select="document($eur-uri)" />
```

Can someone explain me why this is retrieving some data :

```
    <xsl:value-of select="$eur-node//node()[text() = '4.99']/@position" />
```

and this is not ( i get the message "The variable value is unavailable') :

```
    <xsl:variable name="prix-fr" as="xs:string" ><xsl:text>4.99</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$eur-node//node()[text() = $prix-fr]/@position" />
```

I am working with oxygen and saxon 9.5. Any help would be much appreciated.
I am really annoyed because when i put my xpath in xwatch, the second option works... :$

Comment: I don't know: perhaps the error is in code that you haven't shown us. But please note, the message you cite "The variable value is unavailable" is not a known Saxon error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. Finally, it was a problem with the xslt variable debugging tool. The value was not showing up but the transformation worked perfectly.

Comment: I answered very well ;)